# How to calculate the first n even integers?

Tags: c, algorithm

So I am having a hard time calculating the first n even integers, n is the amount of number(s) so an example would be like calculate the first 10 even integers. Down below is the amount of code I was able to come up with

```
int evenNum(int n){
int curr = 2, sum = 0;

for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
  sum += curr;
  curr += 2;
}
return sum;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What makes you think that this code is incorrect?

Comment: This code works fine, if you want the sum of the first n even numbers.

Comment: The formula is `S= n(n+1)/2`

Comment: @PaulBaxter: 1) Try helping him with the Question he's asking before you hand him a higher-level solution, and 2) your formula is off.

Comment: @PaulBaxter No, that sums the first n integers, not the first n even integers.  The correct formula for the first n even integers is just `n*(n+1)`.

Comment: @TomKarzes  https://byjus.com/maths/sum-of-even-numbers/

Comment: @PaulBaxter That page says the same thing I said:  "To find the sum of consecutive even numbers, we need to multiply the above formula by 2. Hence, Se = n(n+1)".  You can test it with a simple spot check:  `f(2)` should be `2 + 4 = 6`, which is `2*(2+1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While solving sum of first `n` kind of problem, make sure to take care of integer overflow. For finding sum of first `n` even numbers, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int evenNumSum(int n) {
        int sum = 0;
        int x = 0;

        while (n--) {
                if (sum > (INT_MAX - x)) {
                        printf ("Integer overflow.\n");
                        sum = -1;
                        break;
                }
                else {  
                        x = x + 2;
                        sum = sum + x;
                }
        }

        return sum;
}

// Driver program
int main(void) {
        int n;
        int res;

        printf ("Enter a number: \n");
        scanf ("%d", &n);

        res = evenNumSum(n);
        if (res >= 0) {
                printf ("Sum of first %d even numbers : %d\n", n, res);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out 
Enter a number: 
5
Sum of first 5 even numbers : 30

# ./a.out
Enter a number: 
10
Sum of first 10 even numbers : 110

# ./a.out
Enter a number: 
46340
Sum of first 46340 even numbers : 2147441940

# ./a.out
Enter a number: 
46341
Integer overflow.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Sum of first **n** even number can be computed in **O(1)** time complexity, using formula `n * (n + 1)`

we know **unsigned long long int** can hold maximum value **(2^64) - 1** or **0 - 18446744073709551614**

To check range of `unsigned long long int` use `printf("ULL_MAX : %llu", ULLONG_MAX);`

**if n = 4294967295**

`n * (n + 1)` = 18446744069414584320 **<** `ULL_MAX`

**if n >= 4294967296**

`n * (n + 1)` >= `ULL_MAX` which can cause integer overflow.

For more info refer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

CODE :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<limits.h>
    #define MAX_N 4294967295
    
    unsigned long long int even_sum(unsigned long int n)
    {
        return (unsigned long long int) n * (n + 1);
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        unsigned long int n;
        
        //printf("ULL_MAX : %llu", ULLONG_MAX);
        printf("Enter Value of n (0 - 4294967295)... ");
        scanf("%lu", &n);
        
        if(n > MAX_N)
            printf("Integer Overflow...");
        else
            printf("Sum of first %lu even numbers is %llu", n, even_sum(n));

        return 0;
    }
```